# How to register jpa converter in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've an entity called `Lawyer` and the following piece of code in a `LawyerRepository`:

```
import javaslang.control.Option;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface LawyerRepository extends JpaRepository<Lawyer, Long> {

    @Query("select distinct l from Lawyer l where l.account.username = :email")
    Option<Lawyer> findLawyerByEmail(@Param("email") String email);

}
```

As you can see I'd like to return `javaslang.control.Option` instead of `java.util.Optional`. It results in the following exception:

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.util.ArrayList] to type
>   [javaslang.control.Option] for value '[lawyer.Lawyer@5e4c0db5]';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type
>   [java.util.ArrayList] to type [javaslang.control.Option]

And here's the converter:

```
import javaslang.control.Option;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@Component
public class OptionConverter implements Converter<ArrayList<?>, Option<?>> {

    @Override
    public Option<?> convert(ArrayList<?> input) {
        if (true) {
            throw new RuntimeException("lol");
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

My question is how to register the converter I provided properly?

Comment: Adding it as a bean should be the only thing you need to do.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I suppose I already have done it but it still fails.

Comment: @M.Deinum doesn't `@Component` do it?

Comment: Not if it isn't in a package that is scanned.

Comment: @M.Deinum it's in package that is scanned. Adding it as a `@Bean` does not work either. Converter is still not found.

Comment: I did make the assumption you had a Spring MVC based application..

Comment: @M.Deinum isn't it rather a matter of spring data?

Comment: No it is the generic converter you need and that is only auto configured if you use Spring MVC. If you don't have Spring MVC no auto configuration of detected converters. You will then have to register a `ConversionService` yourself and add your converter.

Comment: @M.Deinum it doesn't work as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum in this class `QueryExecutionResultHandler` conversion service is created manually hence I guess it's impossible to add custom converter.

Answer (score 2):

Seems Spring's converter(springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter) doesn't work with JPA.

U may have to use JPA Attribute Converter: http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to/.

It's good that Spring can make Spring's converter work with JPA, so it would be consistent as other spring-data-* projects.